# How to pass flag values to subcommands in golang urfave cli

Tags: go

I am using urfave at https://github.com/urfave/cli
to create a CLI with two subcommands.
I am able to create a CLI with a subcommand,
but I really have no idea how to define the flags.
What's the difference between the global flag and local flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each command can optionally specify a 'subcommand'. The subcommand is of type `Command`, which allows for nested / composing commands together.

To achieve something like:

```
cli-tool command1 command2 --command2flag
```

you could have a commands structure like:

```
app := &cli.App{
    //...
    Commands: []*cli.Command{
      {
        Name:    "command1",
        Usage:   // ...
        Action:  //...
        SubCommand: []cli.Command{
           {
               Name: "command2"
               Flags: []cli.Flag{
                  cli.StringFlag{
                     Name: "command2flag"
                     // ...
                  },
               },
           },
        },
      },
    //...
    }
```

You can see here that command2 is nested in command1's subcommands. And the flags for command2 will only apply to command2. This is an example of a local flag.

Global flags would apply to *every* command and subcommand. This could be useful for somekind of config that the cli tool might need to use for all commands. e.g. the server address to talk to etc.

Comment: annoyingly, the global flags must be typed in before any subcommands.  Is there any way to have higher level flags work for lower level commands?